# Disable auto convert links to title of a web page in Trello cards

Tags: trello

I really need links to be links, because it makes impossible to copy cards with copy-paste, links are just text.

May be a handy innovation but not for everyone.

Comment: So frustrating how even when there are thousands of us frustrated PAYING users who hate a feature, Atlassian ignores their requests, and keeps making things worse and worse.

Comment: FYI these are called "Link Previews". They appear for links to some websites and not others. When/how they are shown is not documented. People are asking to be able to disable it [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/How-can-I-disable-links-being-replaced-with-quot-preview-titles/qaq-p/1683772) and [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Link-Previews-appearing-in-trello/qaq-p/1671048) and [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Stop-Trello-from-replacing-a-URL-in-a-card-comment-into-a-page/qaq-p/1686289), and many more.

Answer (score 7):

A few options:

- Use code formatting and surround your link with `backticks`, e.g. `https://mylink.com`. Unfortunately, this makes the link unclickable.
- Format your link, e.g. `[mylink.com](https://mylink.com)` which renders as [mylink.com](https://mylink.com).
- Format your link without the double URL`[https://mylink.com]()` and you don't have to paste your link twice! *(Thanks to @colin-d-bennett 's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154258/disable-auto-convert-links-to-title-of-a-web-page-in-trello-cards/172416#172416).)*

Other than that - I'm with you! I wish they would stop re-formatting things and hitting URLs that I just happen to paste there.

Comment: Backticks worked for me (I don't need the link to be clickable).

Comment: See also the answer by @colin-d-bennett

Answer (score 2):

If you put the URL in a Markdown link as the text, **and leave the URL part blank** (like `[https://example.com/foo]()`, this will convince Trello to stop screwing with your URLs.

And you **don't** have to repeat yourself and write the URL twice.

```
If you put the URL alone, you get this: https://www.cvxpy.org/updates/

But you can stop the madness: [https://www.cvxpy.org/updates/]()
```

Is rendered as:

[image: rendered card]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install this extension:

- Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-preserver-for-trello/kakifckibanjlglpkbnfdichejplgdap
- Firefox Addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-preserver-for-trello

That should work for you, without needing to edit any of your cards.  But it won't do anything for the other members of your workspace.

Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Stop-Trello-from-replacing-a-URL-in-a-card-comment-into-a-page/qaq-p/1686289

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a URL in there, but you don't want it converted by Trello, use the markdown link syntax and just leave a space after the URL.

For example, `[https://mylink.com ](https://mylink.com)` and note the space before the closing square bracket.